How to visualize two OUTPUT metrics for an array of simulations?
GOAL:  visualize simulation output (z) and that time it takes to perform said simulation
CONTEXT:

MATLAB: An array of simulation results can be represented as a matrix f(X,Y).
The simulations are driven by two different independent variables (X,Y)
Simulation output Z is visualized below in the form of surface plot.
The simulation computation time for each simulation is to be visualized with Z.

483 (=21X23) simulations are visualized:

This is acutally a surface plot, whose command is: surfc(nStations,nParameter,data).   The 3D shape is a cliff: the valley is blue (Z=1) and the plateau is yellow (Z=12).  I believe the 3D shape and its eye point does not affect the question.
While looking at Z, it is desirable to be able to see the simulation computuation time of each of the annotated simulations.  In MATLAB parlance:
[simulationTime  z] = f(x,y)
Any suggestions to aid in the visualization of the simulationTime with simulation output (z)?

This is a strange angle for a surface plot. Typically, one would see a 3-dimensional surface. Is this the core of your problem? That you can not see the z-values in this view? Why don't you rotate it?

@Broele  Thank you for the interesting question.   I am familiar with the plot and prefer the Birdseye view.  The 3D surface can be thought of as a cliff.  The blue is a valley (z=1) and yellow is an elevated plateau (z=12).  Changing the eye point  (rotating etc.), does not serve to visualize the simulation times.

My understanding is, that you are not looking for a surface plot, but rather a heat map.
This can give you an image like the one that you showed us and allows for further annotations.

Thank you for commenting: it has helped me to realize that I did not constrain the question enough.  I seek to visualize two output variables: Z and the time it takes to simulate Z.
